# Closest permutations

Tags: c#, algorithm, permutation

I have currently have two lists of 4 3D points, let us call the lists A and B. I want to connect each point in A to one (and only one) point in B such that the total distance between A and B is minimised.

So for example if I have:

A
1: (0,0,0)
2: (0,10,0)
3: (0,20,0)
4: (0,30,0)

B
1: (0,35,10)
2: (0,25,10)
3: (0,15,10)
4: (0,5,10)

The optimal solution would be to connect A1 with B4, A2 with B3, A3 with B2 and A4 with B1.

How would I go about computing this in a reasonable way?

Comment: DP seems reasonable to me: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming

Comment: Easiest way would be brute force it, foreach a in apoints, you calculate the distance beween a to all b's and then take the lowest one.

Comment: @atoMerz DP seems less reasonable to me

Comment: There are only 4! = 24 possibilities. Just try them all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the number of items is small, as it is in your case, you can do this by bruteforcing all permutations in three nested loops:

```
Point3D[] a = new Point3D[4];
Point3D[] b = new Point3D[4];
for (int i = 0 ; i != 4 ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j != 4 ; j++) {
        if (j == i) continue;
        for (int k = 0 ; k != 4 ; k++) {
            int m = 6 - i - j - k;
            if (k == i || k == j || m == i || m == j || m == k) continue;
            var d = a[0].Distance(b[i]) +a[1].Distance(b[j]) + a[2].Distance(b[k]) + a[3].Distance(b[m]);
            min = Math.Min(d, min);
        }
    }
}
```

This finds the minimum in 4! = 24 iterations. If you have more points than, say, more than ten, a much better algorithm is available - you can use the [Hungerian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) to find the minimum-weight matching in polynomial time *O(n<sup>3</sup>)*.

Comment: This is wrong approach. Try any test case where a[0] should be paired with b[3].

Comment: somebody seems to be quite trigger-happy here

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - no. And could you please tell us why you have deleted your first down-voted answer, and created new one with exactly the same answer?

Comment: @SergeyS Because the downvoters were *WRONG*. This *is* in fact a correct answer, it only had smallish bugs

Comment: @NiklasB. I saw the edit, and I realized that my comment was incorrect. I deleted it. Thanks for the edits!

Comment: @Niklas B. - thanks, code looks much better now, however I did not test it. Hope you have tested it. I removed downvote.

Comment: @SergeyS: I did not test it because I can read code and because I don't have Windows or Mono installed. But if there's a bug then I'm sure OP can fix it by themselves. We're not expected to produce production-ready code on Stack Overflow

Comment: This needs to be upvoted because as far as I can see, not only will it produce a correct answer, but it also references the generalized problem by pointing to the Hungarian algorithm.

Comment: @G.Bach I think the downvote is from before the edit that made it a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static IEnumerable<Result> Connect(this IEnumerable<Point> setA, IEnumerable<Point> setB) {
        return setA
            .Select(a => setB.Select(b => new Result { A = a, B = b, D = a.DistanceTo(b) }))
            .SelectMany(s => s)
            .OrderBy(s => s.D)
            .Reduce(new Result[] { }, (a,b) => a.A != b.A && a.B != b.B);
    }
```

using:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Concat<T>(this T h, IEnumerable<T> t) {
        yield return h;
        foreach (var r in t) {
            yield return r;
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<T> Reduce<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, IEnumerable<T> collected, Func<T,T,bool> predicate) {
        if (!items.Any())
            return new T[0];

        var t = items.First();
        var filtered = items.Where(s => predicate(s,t));
        return t.Concat(filtered.Reduce(t.Concat(collected), predicate));
    }
```

where

```
struct Result {
    public Point A;
    public Point B;
    public double D;//distance
}

struct Point {
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public int Z;
}

double DistanceTo(this Point a, Point b) {
    return Math.Sqrt((a.X - b.X) * (a.X - b.X) + (a.Y - b.Y) * (a.Y - b.Y) + (a.Z - b.Z) * (a.Z - b.Z));
}
```

Comment: How does this avoid that one point is assigned to seveal others? Please note that we need a disjoint matching

Comment: each A is connect to only 1 B

Comment: Yes, but a B could be connected to several A's

Comment: Misunderstood that part

Comment: It seems to me that this greedily assigns points to their nearest counterpart in the other set. Please see my comment on Selman's answer for a counterexample of the correctness of this algorithm

Comment: @NiklasB. Not true: (1) +> (1) => 0
(2) +> (2) => 0
(3) +> (3) => 0
(0) +> (-2) => 2 on your example set

Comment: Okay then, does it sort the pairs and greedily take disjoint pairs? Because that will also not work in general, since the pairs don't have a [Matroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid) structure. Do you want me to construct a counter-example or do you think you want to find one yourself?

Comment: I think I'm able to find one myself, but feel free to construct one. That's a test without bias

Comment: A simple counter-example would be `A = [0,3], B = [-2,1]`

Comment: (0) +> (1) => 1
(3) +> (-2) => 5
 optimal = 4. You made your point :-)

Comment: I guess it's a  ε = 1 (factor 2) constant approximation, but I'm not sure.